# Delete Kubernetes namespace only if it's empty?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am using Helm to deploy multiple "components" of my application into a single namespace and using Jenkins to trigger create and destroy jobs. It doesn't seem that I can use Helm to delete the namespace thus I am looking to just use a Kubernetes command.

However, It seems that if I use `kubectl delete namespace` it will forcefully destroy the namespace and all its resources.

I'd like to destroy the namespace only if it is empty. Is there a command to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Remove Empty Namespaces Operator](https://github.com/rgeraskin/remove-empty-ns-operator), it can do exactly what you want.

Why? Because it's not so easy to iterate over resources in the namespace to decide if it's empty or not. After all, there are "default resources" like default service account and probably other stuff from you tooling/operators.

So these resources should be excluded from iteration. Bash scripting becomes too complicated this way. And one day I decided to implement it with Python.

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like destroy the namespace only if it is empty. Is there a command
> to do this?

No there is not command to do that. This behavior is by design.

I would suggest a different approach. You should have all your deployment yamls in version control system for all of the components including namespace. When you want to create use `kubectl create -f deployment.yaml` and when you want to delete use `kubectl delete -f deployment.yaml`

Answer (score 2):

just use folloing to delete all empty namespaces

```
kubectl get ns --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name"  | xargs -I{} kubectl  get all -n {} 2>&1 | grep "No" | cut -d " " -f 5 |  xargs -I{} kubectl delete namespace {}
```

you can list empty namespaces by this

```
kubectl get ns --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name"  | xargs -I{} kubectl  get all -n {} 2>&1 | grep "No" | cut -d " " -f 5
```

Comment: I think the grep might hit other things too "No ressources found" or whatever the message is would ensure that you don't accidentally hit lines which contain that "No" in the ressource Name

Answer (score 1):

You can run `kubectl get all --namespace YOUR_NAMESPACE` and then depends on output call delete namespace

Comment: Unfortunately `get all` [doesn't actually output](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/151) _all_ : /

Comment: yeah this is what im doing now, but realized it doesnt actually output all :(

Comment: You can use this [kubectl plugin](https://github.com/corneliusweig/ketall) to really get ALL.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a simple command to check a namespace before delete, it requires some kubectl scripting or a kube API client.

From the github issue discussing `get all`s limitations [liggit provides](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/151#issuecomment-402003022) an example and adding some jq processing you can get a (slow) command that errors unless it successfully finds all resource types are empty (no `items`):

```
set -o pipefail
kubectl api-resources --verbs=list --namespaced -o name \
 | xargs -n 1 kubectl get --ignore-not-found -n YOUR_NAMESPACE -o json \
 | jq '.items[] | .kind + "/" + .metadata.name | error'
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, better iterate over kube-api resources and this will give every resource list inside the namespace.

```
kubectl api-resources --verbs=list --namespaced -o name \
| xargs -n 1 kubectl get --show-kind --ignore-not-found -l <label>=<value> -n 
<namespace>
```

or another approch

```
kubectl api-resources --verbs=list --namespaced -o name | `
%{ kubectl get $_ --show-kind --ignore-not-found -l <label>=<value> -n 
<namespace> }
```